# How do I show that these are the same logical statement?

Tags: logic, alternative-proof

I know that if I wanna show that the following statement are the same, I may use some rules in Logic: $$P\Longrightarrow Q,\quad [P \text{ and } (\sim Q)]\Longrightarrow [R\text{ and }\sim R]$$ Is there another way or do we just use truth tables?

Answer (score 2):

Well the second statement is just

$$[P~ \text{and}~ (\sim Q)]\Longrightarrow \bot$$

which is just

$$\sim[P~ \text{and}~ (\sim Q)]$$

which is just

$$(\sim P)~ \text{or}~ Q$$

which in classical logic can be taken as the very definition of the first statement.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is with the [method of analytic tableaux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_analytic_tableaux). We argue by contradiction by supposing $\neg ((P\to Q)\leftrightarrow ((P\wedge\neg Q)\to (R\wedge\neg R)))$. This branches immediately so we can do it in parts:
$$\neg (P\to Q)\text{ with }(P\wedge\neg Q)\to (R\wedge\neg R) $$ and
$$P\to Q\text{ with }\neg ((P\wedge\neg Q)\to (R\wedge\neg R)).$$

The second part proceeds like this:
$$P\to Q \\
\neg ((P\wedge\neg Q)\to (R\wedge\neg R)) \\
P\wedge\neg Q \\
\neg (R\wedge\neg R) \\
P \\
\neg Q,
$$

which, from $P\to Q$, has two branches: $\neg P$ and $Q$, both closed (because they contradict the above).

Try the first part yourself. The tableau is below.

> [image]

[These notes (in pdf form)](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CDUQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.personal.psu.edu%2Ft20%2Fnotes%2Flogic.pdf&ei=bOvSUr6hBOqAywO15IH4DQ&usg=AFQjCNH1TML6cltRyC8jzfqH7xWEjh4Mqw&bvm=bv.59026428,d.bGQ) explain the method in detail.

I hope this helps.